# Can't find computer object in AD

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

I replaced ex-sysadmin and there is a laptop that is giving me an error of trust relationship.
The computer object is not available in AD. But, I can ping the computer name.
I don't know the password of the current logged on user and I don't know the local user accounts also.

Can someone please explain why the computer object doesn't exist in AD anymore?
It is giving me the error of security database does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship when I try to log in.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

> The computer object is not available in AD

There is no magic in IT, everything has explanation. Maybe there was a backup restored after computer joining domain or ex-admin deleted the computer account on purpose.

> But, I can ping the computer name

This is not related with computer account be in AD, ping works with icmp protocol and you can ping any computer that is not AD, If you mean how it has resolved the ip address you must investigate further, maybe there is a static record that was added to dns or it was added dynamic or it has the record in server or client cache.

> security database does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship

You want to resolve the issue just rejoin that computer, if you can't login use local admin, if you don't know the password search how to reset local admin password on windows there are many ways to do it.